# How to load all javascript in a directory raw with webpack?

Tags: webpack

I have a bunch of non-module-ized javascript files that are third-party things that I can't (or rather, really don't want to) edit/customize.  I'm trying to load them into my React page (that I created with `create-react-app`, and then `eject`ed so that I can edit the webpack stuff).

Right now, I'm putting all of this third-party stuff into a special folder `include`, so that I can tell webpack to go get all of that stuff and package it special.  [This site](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader) suggested I used `raw-loader` but apparently [that's deprecated](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/) so I've got the following:

```
module.exports =
  ...
  module: {
    ...
    rules: {
      ... 
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          include: [
            path.resolve(__dirname, "include")
          ],
          type: "asset/source"
        },
```

I then `import` these files the usual way:

```
import drawing_utils from "./include/drawing_utils.js"
```

But when `npm run build`ing, I get complaints:

```
src/include/drawing_utils.js
  Line 7:47:    'globalThis' is not defined                                            no-undef
  Line 7:109:   Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 7:115:   Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
  Line 10:117:  Unexpected use of 'self'                                               no-restricted-globals
```

The source code for `drawing_utils.js` is minified (and I don't have access to the unminified version), so I'm not 100% sure how to delve further, but I'd rather not do that anyway because when I test these scripts in a static html page (loading them with `<script>`, they "just work".

How can I use webpack to load my third-party javascript files?

Comment: have you seen in webpack 5 the replacement for the old loaders you mentioned: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/